# How to submit a form with bootbox confirmation

Tags: jquery, forms, bootbox

I have a form that submits checkbox values. Before submission, Bootbox confirmation dialog is shown. But, when click 'yes', form does not submit. How can I fix it? my code is:

```js
$('#student_delete_form').submit(function(e) {
  var currentForm = this;
  e.preventDefault();
  bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    if (result) {
      currentForm.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="student_delete_form" name="" action="#" method="post"></form>
<input type='submit' value='Delete' name='delete' form="student_delete_form"><br>
<?php $studentArray = array(3, 4, 5, 6); ?>
<?php foreach ($studentArray as $key => $value): ?>
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value;?>" form="student_delete_form">
<?php echo $value;?><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){

      $chk=isset($_POST['checkbox'])? $_POST['checkbox']:"";
      if ($chk != "")
      {
        $chk_array=array_filter($chk);

        foreach($chk as $key => $chke)
        {
          echo "$chke";
        }
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're in an endless loop - calling the same function again will just return you back to the same place. You need to then either, call a different function, or, pass an argument into that function that tells itself the user clicked ok, so just submit now

Answer (score 0):

You're in an endless loop - calling the same function again will just return you back to the same place.

You can try  following javascript

```
$("input[name='delete']").on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    if (result) {
      $('#student_delete_form').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: those just give loop of dialog confirmation or no submit at all

Comment: it's fine :) but actually I already tried updated code, and it will not work too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the confirm as just that, try this (not tested but should be close)

```
$("input[name='delete']").click(function() {
  bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    if (result) {
      $('#student_delete_form').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

**Update**

remove `form="student_delete_form"` from the 'delete' button

**Update 2**

If you don't want to remove the form attribute from the 'delete' button:

```
$("input[name='delete']").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    if (result) {
      $('#student_delete_form').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle showing the code working as it should](http://jsfiddle.net/gLggf24z/1/)

Comment: if remove e.preventDefault(); , Bootbox confirmation dialog will not show.

Comment: I've added a fiddle to the answer, it all works as planned so might be something else preventing it

Comment: Only to show alert is fine, but can't pass values in submitted form. or, I have to add another submit function to pass PHP values ?
btw, I did workaround to get result i want. Thank, anyway :)